# Merge two files using formula

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk, sed

I need to merge two files using some rules. The first `file1` has x users and `file2` has y users; in file 1, only users that have 1 at $4 are available.

It should search the 3rd column of the file, the "IPxx" (the IPxx is unique for each user and can contain spaces in xx), and compare it to the 5th column of file 2 (without the IP, xx match xx). If it finds a match it merges the two using this formula (F1 is File1; F2 is File 2):

**$2**(F1):**$1**(F1):**$2**(F2):**$1**(F2):**$3**(F1):**yyyy/mm/dd**(today's date)

I did this to find who is available on File1:

```
sed 's/\IP//' File1.txt | awk -F '(:)' '{if($4==1)print $2":"$1":"$3}'
```

And organize File2

```
awk -F '(:)' '{print $2":"$1":"$3}'
```

Now how can I compare the two of them and merge them together using that formula?

Example:

File1

```
123:bacon white:IPES:0
456:eggs grey:IPUS:1
789:ham yellow:IPUK:1
```

File2

```
1:foo foo:ES:abc
2:bar bar:US:def
3:tmp tmp:ES:ghi
4:baz baz:UK:jkl
5:qux qux:US:mno
6:spam spam:UK:pqr
7:xyz xyz:UK:stu
```

Output File

```
eggs grey:456:bar bar:2:IPUS:2021/03/10
eggs grey:456:qux qux:5:IPUS:2021/03/10
ham yellow:789:baz baz:4:IPUK:2021/03/10
ham yellow:789:spam spam:6:IPUK:2021/03/10
ham yellow:789:xyz xyz:7:IPUK:2021/03/10
```

Comment: Since file1 line1 has `ES` and file2 lines 1 & 3 have `ES`, why don't you show `bacon white:123:foo foo:1:IPES:2021/03/10`? and the same for `ES` and `tmp tmp`?

Comment: Because 123:bacon white:IPES:0 ends with 0, only the ones that end with 1 are available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -v date="$(date +"%Y/%m/%d")" '
            BEGIN   {FS=OFS=":"} 
            NR==FNR {f3=$3; sub(/^IP/,"",f3); a[f3]=$0; next} 
            $3 in a {split(a[$3],p); 
                     print p[2],p[1],$2,$1,p[3],date}' file1 file2

bacon white:123:foo foo:1:IPES:2021/03/09
eggs grey:456:bar bar:2:IPUS:2021/03/09
bacon white:123:tmp tmp:3:IPES:2021/03/09
ham yellow:789:baz baz:4:IPUK:2021/03/09
eggs grey:456:qux qux:5:IPUS:2021/03/09
ham yellow:789:spam spam:6:IPUK:2021/03/09
ham yellow:789:xyz xyz:7:IPUK:2021/03/09
```

ES also matches, not sure what they are not in your expected output.

while scanning the first file (`NR==FNR`) construct the key by stripping prefix from the third column and save the whole record with that key in a map (in order to not modify 3rd field assign to a temp variable first).

For the second file, check if 3rd field is in the map, if so split the previously saved record and extract the fields and print in order.

Pass the date in the desired format as a variable to the script and print it as well.

If you want to exclude the records based on the 4th field value, add the filter in the mapping stage

```
NR==FNR {if($4) {f3=$3 ... }}
```

Comment: At least by my read, this is what he is looking for, though I'm still confused on why he shows the output he does??

Comment: Because 123:bacon white:IPES:0 ends with 0, only the ones that end with 1 are available. But I just removed every line that match pattern. Thank u

Comment: @TsYn please see the updated explanation and filtering unwanted records.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with GNU command line utilities `join`, `grep`, `sed`, `sort`, and `date`:

```
today=$(date +%Y/%m/%d)
join -t: -j3 -o1.2,1.1,2.2,2.1,1.3 \
  <(grep ':1$' file1 | sort -t: -k3,3) \
  <(sed -E 's/([^:]*)(:[^:]*)$/IP\1\2/' file2 | sort -t: -k3,3) |
sed "s%\$%:${today}%" |
sort -t: -n -k2,2
```

Output:

```
eggs grey:456:bar bar:2:IPUS:2021/03/10
eggs grey:456:qux qux:5:IPUS:2021/03/10
ham yellow:789:baz baz:4:IPUK:2021/03/10
ham yellow:789:spam spam:6:IPUK:2021/03/10
ham yellow:789:xyz xyz:7:IPUK:2021/03/10
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and sort):

```
sed -nE '1{x;s/^/cat file1/e;x};G
         s#^([^:]*):([^:]*):(..):(...)(\n[^\n]*)*\n([^:]*):([^:]*):(IP\3):1.*#\7:\6:\2:\1:\8:'"$(date +%Y/%m/%d)"'#p' file2 |
sort -k2,2n
```

Copy file1 into the hold space.

Append file 1 to each line of file2 and extract the details in the required order from the composite lines.

Sort the output by the numeric field 2.